# Copy first N files from source directory to "serialized" destination directory using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Either Powershell or batch script will work. I want to distribute every N number of files from directory A to directory B1, B2, B3, etc.

Example: 
C:\a (has 9 .jpg files)
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
...
file9.jpg

then c:\b1, C:\b2, C:\b3 should have 3 files each. it should create directories C:\b* as well.

So far I came up with this code, works fine but copies ALL the files from directory A to directory B:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\a"
$destinationFolder = "C:\b"
$maxItems = 9
Get-Childitem  $sourceFolder\*.jpg | ForEach-Object {Select-Object -First $maxItems | Robocopy $sourceFolder $destinationFolder /E /MOV}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works, will calculate how many new folders should be created.

```
$excludealreadycopieditems = @()
$sourcefolder = "C:\a"
$destinationFolder = "C:\b"
$maxitemsinfolder = 3
#Calculate how many folders should be created:
$folderstocreate = [math]::Ceiling((get-childitem $sourcefolder\*.jpg).count / $maxitemsinfolder)
#For loop for the proces
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $folderstocreate + 1; $i++)
     {
#Create the new folders:
New-Item -ItemType directory $destinationFolder$i
#Copy the items (if moving in stead of copy use Move-Item)
get-childitem $sourcefolder\*.jpg -Exclude $excludealreadycopieditems | sort-object name | select -First $maxitemsinfolder | Copy-Item -Destination $destinationFolder$i ;
#Exclude the already copied items:
$excludealreadycopieditems = $excludealreadycopieditems + (get-childitem $destinationFolder$i\*.jpg | select -ExpandProperty name)
     }
```

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a charm... it does create 3 different directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
$cnt = 0
$i   = 1
Get-ChildItem "$sourceFolder\*.jpg" | % {
  if ($script:cnt -ge $maxItems) {
    $script:i++
    $script:cnt = 0
  }

  $dst = "$destinationFolder$script:i"
  if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst)) {
    New-Item $dst -Type Directory | Out-Null
  }
  Copy-Item $_.FullName $dst

  $script:cnt++
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not create 3 different directories. Though copies all files in 1 directory... which is what the program I wrote does eventually anyway.

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work. I had to change to `$sourceFolder\*.jpg`(without double quotes) and to `New-Item $destinationFolder$i` (with $i at the end) and it did went through a little bit. but i had 8 files in c:\a and it create c:\b with 4 files and C:\b\1 with another 4 files directory.

Comment: @user5084064 The code in my answer worked fine when I tested it. Please provide evidence.

Comment: 1) it creates empty directory b 2) it also creates b1 b2... bn files if there are n files in c:\a directory `New-Item : Item with specified name C:\b already exists.
At C:\ansgar.ps1:12 char:13
+     New-Item <<<<  $destinationFolder -Type Directory | Out-Null
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\b:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`

Comment: @user5084064 The `New-Item` statement in my sample code doesn't use the variable `$destinationFolder`. Please edit your question and show the actual code you're using.

Comment: Aaah! My bad, got it. I tried to fix few things and didn't notice that. Yours works too but just a minor change. `$i = 1` as it should create given destDir in a series. e.g. destDir_1, destDir_2. Your code does it to except the 1st directory. which is same as defined destination directory. Thanks for all your help. You rock!!